# TinyMCE external image list with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, image, list, jquery-plugins, tinymce

I'm trying to use an external image list with the TinyMCE editor that's be initialized using MoxieCode's jQuery plugin, but I'm getting an error from TinyMCE itself.

Here's the code that initializes TinyMCE:

```
$code_editors.tinymce({
                    script_url : '/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
                    external_image_list_url : "/assets/mce_cache.js",
                    theme : "advanced",
                    content_css : "/css/style.css,http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Stint+Ultra+Condensed",
                    height: '400px',
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left"
                });
```

Here's the contents of my image list (this file is found at `/assets/mce_cache.js`)

```
var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(
  ["2012-birkie-all.jpg", "/assets/Asset-00016_2012-birkie-all.jpg"],
  ["bike-part-bg-bottom-bracket.png", "/assets/Asset-00010_bike-part-bg-bottom-bracket.png"],
  ["bike-part-bg-chainrings.png", "/assets/Asset-00011_bike-part-bg-chainrings.png"],
  ["bike-part-bg-fork-red.png", "/assets/Asset-00015_bike-part-bg-fork-red.png"],
  ["bike-part-bg-fork.png", "/assets/Asset-00012_bike-part-bg-fork.png"],
  ["bike-part-bg-frame.png", "/assets/Asset-00013_bike-part-bg-frame.png"],
  ["bike-part-bg-saddle.png", "/assets/Asset-00014_bike-part-bg-saddle.png"],
  ["Purge Photo", "/assets/Asset-00022_ePurge-1.jpg"]
);
```

And the error I'm getting (in Chrome) is in `editor_template.js:1` (a TinyMCE file):

`Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'indexOf'`

Does anyone have experience with TinyMCE's use of external image lists that might see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit enter in the tags box and this posted before I was done.  The error's been added now.

Comment: Well line 1 is quite broad since your editor_template.js is probably minimized. What you should do is replace it with a developer version and check which line. Apparently (well atleast, my guess) somewhere something is evaluating to false, which should be an object instead. I don't have any experience with TinyMCE's use of external image lists so I don't know any specifics, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was located on line 1402 of an unminified version of the `editor_template.js`.  The code that caused the problem was:

`if (ed.dom.getAttrib(ed.selection.getNode(), 'class').indexOf('mceItem') != -1)`

The `getAttrib()` method takes up to three arguments, the 3rd being the default value to return if the specified attribute doesn't exist.  By changing the code to:

`if (ed.dom.getAttrib(ed.selection.getNode(), 'class', '').indexOf('mceItem') != -1)`

An empty string, and not `false`, is returned when there's no class attribute.  This seems to have resolved the issue and my image list is now loading properly.